# Avoid Matrix copy constructor

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have a situation like this:

```cpp
using JacobiSVD = Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixXcd, Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQRPreconditioner>;

class Foo {
    public:
        MatrixXcd matrixU;
        MatrixXcd matrixV;

        Foo(const Ref<const MatrixXcd>& mat);
}

Foo::Foo(const Ref<const MatrixXcd>& mat) {
    JacobiSVD svd(mat, Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV);
    matrixU = svd.matrixU();
    matrixV = svd.matrixV();

    // <proceed to mutate computeU and computeV>
}
```

I think the above creates a copy of `svd.matrixU()` and `svd.matrixV()` during construction of `matrixU` and `matrixV`. Is this true, and is there some way to avoid it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No temporary copies are created during the construction of `matrixU` and `matrixV`. `Eigen::JacobiSVD` inherits from `Eigen::SVDBase`, which defines the member functions `matrixU()` and `matrixV()` which just return a *reference* to the protected member variables of `Eigen::SVDBase` that hold the actual matrices.

However, you are still copying data, but explicitly: you copy the two matrices from the local variable `svd` into member variables of `Foo`. If you do not need to modify the U and V matrices in-place, you could store the whole `svd` in `Foo`, like so:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        JacobiSVD svd;
        Foo(const Ref<const MatrixXcd>& mat);
};

Foo::Foo(const Ref<const MatrixXcd>& mat):
    svd(mat,  Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV) {
    // proceed to do other things
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't modify the member variables of `svd`. So if you really need to modify them, and don't need the original values, then your code is fine as it is.

Comment: In particular, since the functions return *`const`* references, you can’t move them out of the SVD instance.